# Sum of entries of the inverse of a positive definite matrix $I_{l} + A_1A_1^T + A_2A_2^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, positive-definite

Let $A_1$ be an $\ell \times n$ matrix and $A_2$ be an $\ell \times m$ matrix, where $\ell \ge n, m$. The entries of $A_1$ and $A_2$ are only $0$'s and $1$'s such that

1. Each row has exactly one $1$, and
2. Each column has at least one $1$.

Let $A_1'$ be an $(\ell+1) \times n$ matrix formed by adding to $A_1$ a $k$th row that consists of one $1$ with all other entries being $0$'s, where $k \le \ell+1$. Similarly let $A_2'$ be an $(\ell+1) \times m$ matrix formed by adding to $A_2$ a $k$th row that consists of one $1$ with all other entries being $0$'s. The position of 1 in each added row is arbitrary and independent.

**How to show that the sum of all entries of $(I_{\ell+1} + A_1'A_1'^T + A_2'A_2'^T)^{-1}$ is greater than or equal to the sum of all entries of $(I_{\ell} + A_1A_1^T + A_2A_2^T)^{-1}$?**

I can show that $I_{\ell} + A_1A_1^T + A_2A_2^T$ is positive definite (since $I$ is positive definite and the two products are both positive semidefinite). I tried different formulae for the inverse of the sum of matrices, e.g., based on the Woodbury matrix identity, but no approach has panned out so far.

Edit: Alternatively, it suffices to show the result when the new rows are added to the bottoms of the matrices.

Comment: You might find the following to be a helpful simplification: let $A$ denote the matrix $A = [A_1 \ \ A_2]$ and $v_1,\dots,v_{m+n}$ the columns of $A$. We can write 
$$
I + A_1A_1^T + A_2A_2^T = I + AA^T = I + \sum_{i=1}^{m+n} v_iv_i^T.
$$

Comment: Why don't you use block matrices?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thank you! Do you mean separating the last added row?

Comment: Just append the last row to a block. Visually, it's easier

Comment: Any progress???

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I haven't had a chance to delve into it yet. Busy with other work.